# template_fetch_template hook $row parameter

Tags: templates, extension, hook

I'm considering writing an extension that greatly depends on hooks that are available before and during template parsing. I see in the [ExpressionEngine hook documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/template/index.html#template-fetch-template) that there is a hook called 'template_fetch_template' and its parameter is an array of template data called $row. I can't tell from the documentation *exactly* what data is in that array. What are the array indexes and what kind of content do they possess?

Comment: Whenever exploring an extension hook that receives one or more arguments, I just write a dummy extension that just does this: `var_dump($passed_arg); exit();`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is array_keys($row):

```
Array
(
    [0] => template_id
    [1] => site_id
    [2] => group_id
    [3] => template_name
    [4] => save_template_file
    [5] => template_type
    [6] => template_data
    [7] => template_notes
    [8] => edit_date
    [9] => last_author_id
    [10] => cache
    [11] => refresh
    [12] => no_auth_bounce
    [13] => enable_http_auth
    [14] => allow_php
    [15] => php_parse_location
    [16] => hits
    [17] => group_name
)
```

`template_data` is probably the most interesting one. It contains the unparsed template code. Note that you cannot change the template code directly (because $row is a copy not a reference), but you can *prepend* to the $this->EE->config->_global_vars array with a key that consists of a substring from the template code (or indeed, the entire template code could be the key). As the globals array is replaced into the template later on this gives you a mechanism for manipulating the template code before it is parsed.

Comment: injecting template in globals key, sneaky crox :-)   edit: but aren't globals replaced with curly brackets around them? e.g. `{keyname}` ?

Comment: They are indeed so yes the bit you want replaced needs to at least be enclosed by braces {}. I use it for including other templates early on via {stash:embed}.